# "removeFromSuperview" NEVER work on UIApplication?

Tags: ios, swift

How to remove subviews?

I am trying to integrate GIF by creating `UIView` and `UIImageView` programmatically.

It works fine to show GIF but when the function of hiding if is called, there is no response.

Here are the codes of both functions.

```
class CustomLoader: UIView {

    static let instance = CustomLoader()

    var viewColor: UIColor = .black
    var setAlpha: CGFloat = 0.5
    var gifName: String = ""

    lazy var transparentView: UIView = {
        let transparentView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height))
        transparentView.backgroundColor = viewColor.withAlphaComponent(setAlpha)
        transparentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        return transparentView
    }()

    lazy var gifImage: UIImageView = {
        var gifImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 60))
        gifImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        gifImage.center = transparentView.center
        gifImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        gifImage.loadGif(name: gifName)
        return gifImage
    }()

    func showLoaderView() {
        self.addSubview(self.transparentView)
        self.transparentView.addSubview(self.gifImage)
        self.transparentView.bringSubview(toFront: self.gifImage)
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(transparentView)

    }

    func hideLoaderView() {
        self.transparentView.removeFromSuperview()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. I’d suggest you add a breakpoint or a logging statement in `hideLoaderView` and make sure you’re getting to that line.
2. You should make the `init` method to this class `private` to make sure you’re not calling `hideLoaderView` on some separate instance. When dealing with singletons, you want to make sure you can’t accidentally create another instance.

But I tested your code, and it works fine. Your problem probably rests with where and how you call this (and making `init` `private`, you might find where you might be using it inappropriately).

In the comments below, you said:

> I simply call the function "CustomLoader().hideLoaderView()" Both are being called technically. What do you mean by "where I using it inappropriately?"

That is the root of the problem.

The `CustomLoader()` of `CustomLoader().hideLoaderView()` will create a new instance of `CustomLoader` with its own `transparencyView`, etc., which is precisely what the problem is. You’re not hiding the old view that was presented earlier, but trying to hide another one that you just created and was never displayed.

If you instead use that `static`, e.g. `CustomLoader.instance.showLoaderView()` and `CustomLoader.instance.hideLoaderView()`, then the problem will go away. Then you will be hiding the same view that your previously showed.

---

By the way, a few other unrelated observations:

3. If this is a singleton or shared instance, the convention would be to call that `static` property `shared`, not `instance`.
4. By the way, you aren’t using this `CustomLoader` as a `UIView`, so I’d not make it a `UIView` subclass. Don’t make it a subclass of anything.

   You would obviously eliminate that `self.addSubview(transparentView)` line, too.
5. The `bringSubview(toFront:)` call is unnecessary.
6. You should avoid referencing `UIScreen.main.bounds`. You don’t know if your app might be in multitasking mode (maybe this isn’t an issue right now, but it’s the sort of unnecessary assumption that will cause problems at some later date). Just refer to the `bounds` of the `UIWindow` to which you’re adding this. You should also update this `frame` when you show this view, not when you create it (in case you changed orientation in the intervening time, or whatever).

   By the way, using `keyWindow` is discouraged in iOS 13 and later, so you might eventually want to remove that, too.
7. When adding the `gifImage` (which I’d suggest renaming to `gifImageView` because it’s an image view, not an image), you should not reference the `center` of its superview. That’s the coordinate of the transparent view in its super view’s coordinate system, which could be completely different than the transparent view’s own coordinate system. In this case, it just happens to work, but it suggests a fundamental misunderstanding of view coordinate systems. Reference the `bounds` of the `transparentView`, not its `center`.
8. If you’re going to expose `viewColor` and `setAlpha`, you should pull the setting of the `transparentView`’s color out of the `lazy` initializer and into `showLoaderView`, at the very least. Right now, if you show the loader once, and then change the color, and try to show it again, you won’t see the new color.
9. The same issue applies with the gif image. So, I’d move that to the `didSet` observer.

Thus, pulling this all together:

```
class CustomLoader{
    static let shared = CustomLoader()

    private init() { }

    var dimmingColor: UIColor = .black
    var dimmingAlpha: CGFloat = 0.5

    var gifName: String = "" { didSet { gifImage.loadGif(name: gifName) } }

    lazy var transparentView: UIView = {
        let transparentView = UIView()
        transparentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        return transparentView
    }()

    lazy var gifImageView: UIImageView = {
        var gifImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 60))
        gifImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        gifImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        return gifImage
    }()

    func showLoaderView() {
        guard let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow else { return }
        transparentView.frame = window.bounds
        transparentView.backgroundColor = dimmingColor.withAlphaComponent(dimmingAlpha)
        gifImageView.center = CGPoint(x: transparentView.bounds.midX, y: transparentView.bounds.midY)
        transparentView.addSubview(gifImageView)
        window.addSubview(transparentView)
    }

    func hideLoaderView() {
        transparentView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Rob,

I simply call the function "CustomLoader().hideLoaderView()" 
Both are being called technically. What do you mean by "where I using it inappropriately?" Because if it can be shown why it does not work in hiding function.(I call it over tableView)

One more question please, I had tried "transparentView.subviews.forEach{ $0.removeFromSuperview()}" and adding tag to the view then  call "self.transparentView.viewWithTag(200)?.removeFromSuperview()"
Both don't work as well. What do you think?

Thanks

Comment: The `CustomLoader()` of `CustomLoader().hideLoaderView()` will create a new instance of `CustomLoader` with its own `transparencyView`, etc., which is precisely what the problem is. You’re not hiding the old view that was presented earlier, but trying to hide another one that you just created and was never displayed. If you have that `static` called `instance` (or `shared` in my rendition), so use that, e.g. `CustomLoader.shared.showLoaderView()` and `CustomLoader.shared.hideLoaderView()`. Then you’re hiding the same view that your previously showed.

Comment: By making `init` private, it makes it harder to accidentally create a new instance like you have. Now, if you don’t want to use that `static` property, fine, but you should then get rid of that property and keep track of the original `CustomLoader` instance yourself. I inferred from that `static`, though, that you wanted to use `CustomLoader` as a singleton. If it’s not, then that `static` doesn’t belong there at all.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, Rob
It's all clear now. Glad I messed up with the new instance. If not, I would not know the function is inappropriately called by accessing CustomLoader() directly.
What I can give back to you?

Comment: Well said, Rob

I will definitely do that.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using transparentView while you are have a CustomLoader instance view

Try to use this

```swift
class CustomLoader: UIView {

    static let instance = CustomLoader()

    var viewColor: UIColor = .black
    var setAlpha: CGFloat = 0.5
    var gifName: String = ""

    init() {
        super.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        backgroundColor = viewColor.withAlphaComponent(setAlpha)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    lazy var gifImage: UIImageView = {
        var gifImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 60))
        gifImage.backgroundColor = .red
        gifImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        gifImage.center = center
        gifImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        gifImage.loadGif(name: gifName)
        return gifImage
    }()

    func showLoaderView() {
        addSubview(self.gifImage)
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(self)

    }
    func hideLoaderView() {
        removeFromSuperview()
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, Mahmoud
I tried this method before. Ain't working for me, mate
The GIF never disappears.

Thanks